# Doing an indicator in TradingView pine v4

Tags: pine-script

Im new at this, im doing something very easy but idk why it cant compile.

This is the script:

```
//@version=4
study("CrossOver", overlay = true)
sma_1 = sma (close, 4)
sma_2 = sma (close, 9)
sma_3 = sma (close, 18)

plot(sma_1, color = color.white)
plot(sma_2, color = color.red)
plot(sma_3, color = color.green)

longs = (sma_1 > sma_2) and (sma_2 > sma_3)
shorts = (sma_1 < sma_2) and (sma_2 < sma_3)
bgcolor(longs ? color.green : na)
bgcolor(shorts ? color.red : na)
```

And this is the error when I compile:

```
line 10: Undeclared identifier `color.white`;
line 11: Undeclared identifier `color.red`;
line 12: Undeclared identifier `color.green`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script compiles fine here:

[image]